# Why is it showing "I/O operation on closed file" in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project in which a user uploads a file from the front-end and without storing the file it goes to the backend where some processing is done and results are returned back. Here are the functions which are dealing these works in the **views.py** file:

```
def midpro(request, *args):
    global file
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        try:
            file = request.FILES['data']
        except:
            print("No File")
    if(file!=None):
        if(file.name[-1:-4:-1]!="vsc"):
            return render(request, 'mapp/nocsv.html')
        else:
            return linml(request)
    return render(request, 'mapp/nofile.html')

def linml(request, *args):
    global retdata
    global file
    ans = list()
    col = ['D1', 'D2']
    if(file!=None):
        ins = mapp.Mapp(file)
        retdata = ins.linml()
    for i in zip(col, retdata):
        ans.append(i)
    context = {
        'ans':ans,
        'data':file
    }
    return render(request, 'mapp/linml.html', context)
```

the code inside **Mapp** class is

```
class Mapp:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def linml(self, *args):
        data = pd.read_csv(self.file)
        data = np.array(data)
        return([np.mean(data), np.var(data)])
```

`pd` is the alias for `pandas` library.

`np` is the alias for `numpy` library.

the error **I/O operation on closed file** is occuring in `data = pd.read_csv(self.file)` step.

Can anyone tell me how can i resolve this issue?

Also if I try to explicitly open the file with:

```
with open(self.file) as f:
```

It shows **expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile** error, which i guess means that the file is already opened.

So, anyone please tell me why **I/O operation on closed file** is happening!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a bug with the code you are showing. However, I do see you use `global file`. Using globals is never a good idea, especially if you call them `file`! I would suggest you refactor your code so that it doesn't use globals and probably the bug will then disappear by itself. Good luck.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga I've tried what you've said but still it's showing the same error.

Comment: You should now update the question accordingly.

Comment: Also, just paste the full error stack trace. There mind be more information in there.